# Should I use "Written quote […]” or "Written quote […]”. with a period?

Tags: punctuation

The full sentence is:

> According to Zhao et al. (2019), “[there] is no convenient
>   experimental access to the internal variable D[…]”.

I'm uncertain if I need that last period.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what *[...]* means.

Yes, you need a last period.

In American English, it goes before the quotation mark. In British English, it goes after.

In American English, periods and commas always go before. Question marks and exclamation points only go before if they're part of the quote.

The British are more consistent. Their commas and periods (they say *full stops*) only go before the quotation mark if they're part of the quote.